# Most efficient technique to check lots of cells contain an error?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which contains lots of function calls to request data. I am writing a function (in VBA) to check whether any of the cells contains an error value "#VALUE" etc.

At the moment I am iterating row by row, column by column and first checking if the cell contains a formula, then if it does, checking instr for "#VALUE", "#N/A" etc.

However, I was wondering whether it would be quicker simulating clicking a whole column in excel and then "ctrl + f" for a value... in VBA.

What would be the most efficient way? I am checking a sheet 27 columns x 1200 rows large.

EDIT Ive just realised there are some cells which have "#N/A" and this is because they do not contain a particular formula. I need to only search in cells which contain a particular formula.... is this possible?

EDIT2 I effectively need to record a macro which returns the resutls, exactly like "find all". I have used "find" and i can get a boolean, but "find all" doesnt record any VBA code....

Comment: What formula do you wish to check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `SpecialCells` to return only cells containing errors.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set rng = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "No Errors"
        Else
            For Each cl In rng
                If cl.Formula Like "*" Then  ' <-- replace * with your criteria
                    Debug.Print cl.Address
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you wanted the most efficient method you could try this approach which avoids a slow range loop

1. Loops through `SpecialCells` formulae chichi contain errors (as per the other solution)
2. Uses `Find` to detect specific formulae rather than a simple loop through every cell in (1)

This code uses the `R1C1` method to feed into the `Find` so the code changes this `Application` setting if necessary (and then back at the end)

I suggest you record the formula you wish to find to then enter this in. The big advantage of `R1C1` notation is that it is agnostic of actual row and column location.

For example in `A1` notation a formula of

- =SUM(A1:A4) in `A5` would require a different search for `SUM(B1:B4) in`B5`
- in `R1C1` this is `=SUM(R[-4]C:R[-1]C)` in both cases

**code**

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim bRefSTyle

    If Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1 Then
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
        bRefSTyle = True
    End If

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set rng1 = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rng1 Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print ws.Name & ": No Formulae errors"
        Else
            'search errors for particular formula
            'this sample looks for a formula which SUMS the four cells directly above it
            Set rng2 = rng1.Find("=SUM(R[-4]C:R[-1]C)", , xlFormulas, xlWhole)
            If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                strAddress = rng2.Address
                Set rng3 = rng2
                Do
                 Set rng2 = rng1.Find("=SUM(R[-4]C:R[-1]C)", rng2, xlFormulas, xlWhole)
                    Set rng3 = Union(rng2, rng3)
                Loop While strAddress <> rng2.Address
                Debug.Print ws.Name & ": " & rng3.Address
            Else
                Debug.Print ws.Name & ": error cells, but no formulae match"
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'restore styles if necessary
    If bRefSTyle Then Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
End Sub
```